# How do I edit a plesk subdomain home folder from command line

Tags: plesk

How do I edit a plesk subdomain home folder from command line in Linux?

I can create the subdomain and assign the home folder from command no problem but now I need to update the home folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like:

plesk bin subdomain -u subdomain.domain.com -www-root /var/www/vhosts/subdomain.doman.com/wwwroot

More details you can find with help of:

plesk bin subdomain --help